# How do you set bevel profile to less than 0.15

Tags: bevel

Just wondering is it possible to set bevel profile to less than 0.15?

I need it for this particular case: I want to match this bevel's "[profile](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/bevel.html)" to the other bevels. But can't.

[image]

If setting it to less than 0.15 is not possible in GUI, then perhaps there are other workaround?

So far I think boolean op (subtract by a cylinder) might be a best idea.